# Highstock disable tooltip for one series

Tags: highcharts

I have multiple series on highstock, wants to disable tooltip for one series. 
I want to disable tooltip for "MSFT" series.

```
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'ADBE',
            data: ADBE
        }, {
            name: 'MSFT',
            data: MSFT,
            visible: true
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'ADBE',
        data: ADBE
    }, {
        name: 'MSFT',
        data: MSFT,
        visible: true,
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: ''
        }
    }]
```

Just for that one series. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/t8Lm6y5x/

Comment: Thanks Pawel, It's working perfectly.. And adding one more question, Is it possible to disable highlight data lable on mouse hover for disabled tooltip series?

Comment: Sure, all options from plotOptions can be used for specific series. See [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.funnel.enableMouseTracking).

Comment: Thanks Pawel, I added "enableMouseTracking: false", It's working perfectly.